# Sampling 10% of cells in terra raster in R

Tags: r, terra

(I am new to spatial analysis so please excuse if this is an obvious question)

In terra, I have a SpatRaster of the world at 1km resolution (3006072000 cells, 5 layers). I would like to randomly sample 10% of the cells in this spatial raster as a subset raster without changing the resolution of the raster.

I have tried the spatSample function in terra (specifying the size as 10% of my original raster's size), but the output is a raster with a resolution that is also 10x lower.
I would like a "patchy" raster with 10% of the cells at 1km resolution present for my next analysis step (which relies on the raster being transformed into a dataframe, I can't make a dataframe at 1km resolution for the whole world without R crashing).

Is there a way to do this? Or an obvious reason why this wouldn't be a good approach?

Comment: You may want to give `tidyterra::slice_sample()` a try, see examples https://dieghernan.github.io/tidyterra/reference/slice.Spat.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want a random sample that includes everything (terrestrial and ocean)? If so, then just sample a vector that is 1:n, these values would then relate to the cell numbers and can be indexed.

First, create example data

```
library(terra)

r <- rast(nrow=100, ncol=100)
  r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
```

Then, take a copy of the raster and turn all non-sampled data to NA's. This is done by sampling the cell vector "v", indexing the raster and piping NA. This will also work across multiple bands because the cell number remain the same.

```
r.samp <- r
v <- cells(r) 
  r.samp[v[-sample(v, round(ncell(r) * 0.10, 0))]] <- NA 
plot(c(r, r.samp))
```

A break down is that we are removing our random sample `sample(v, round(ncell(r) * 0.10, 0))]` from the cell number vector `v`. This is done as an index of `r.sample` allowing us to assign NA's to all non-sampled cells thus, resulting in the randomly sampled raster.

Since the `terra::cells` function returns cell numbers for non-NA cells then if you want to limit the sampling just reclassify the raster into NA values wherever you do not want samples.